# jQuery: Load Modal Dialog Contents via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, modal-dialog

Currently my Modal Dialog is like this

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Title Box">
   <p>Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(
    function() {
     jQuery("#dialog")
      .dialog(
       {
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true
       }
      );
     jQuery('body')
      .bind(
       'click',
       function(e){
        if(
         jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
         && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
         && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
        ){
         jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
       }
      );
    }
   );
  </script>
  <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">Click to view</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

The Div that is loaded is included in the same page. How do I move that div to a second page and load the contents via Ajax when the dialog is shown? And can I reuse the script to load different contents as per need?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Check out this blog post from Nemikor, which should do what you want.

http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/

Basically, before calling 'open', you 'load' the content from the other page first.

```
jQuery('#dialog').load('path to my page').dialog('open');
```

Comment: although this works it will open the dialog immediately rather than waiting for load to complete.  would be better to use a callback function like: `$('#dialog').load('path-to-my-page', function() { $('#dialog').dialog('open'); });`

Answer (score 14):

try to use this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "yourPageWhereToLoadData.php",
    success: function(data){
        $("#dialog").html(data);
    }   
});

$("#dialog").dialog(
       {
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true
       }
);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function ()    {
    $('<div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function ()
        {
            $(this).load('Sample.htm');
        },         
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
    });
});
```

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/load-page-dynamically-inside-jquery-ui.html

Answer (score 5):

```
var dialogName = '#dialog_XYZ';
$.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_pages/my_page.ext",
        data: {....},
        success: function(data) {
          $(dialogName ).remove();

          $('BODY').append(data);

          $(dialogName )
            .dialog(options.dialogOptions);
        }
});
```

The Ajax-Request load the Dialog, add them to the Body of the current page and open the Dialog.

If you only whant to load the content you can do:

```
var dialogName = '#dialog_XYZ';
$.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_pages/my_page.ext",
            data: {....},
            success: function(data) {
              $(dialogName).append(data);

              $(dialogName )
                .dialog(options.dialogOptions);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn" onClick="openDialog('New Type','Sample.html')">Middle</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDialog(title,url) {
        $('.opened-dialogs').dialog("close");

        $('<div class="opened-dialogs">').html('loading...').dialog({
            position:  ['center',20],
            open: function () {
                $(this).load(url);

            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
            },

            title: title,
            minWidth: 600            
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this code may give you some idea.

**http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```