# Retrieve a variable from jQuery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I want to load a page into jQuery Dialog plugin (by using that code [jQuery: Load Modal Dialog Contents via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837166/jquery-load-modal-dialog-contents-via-ajax)) In that page user will select some data. After the selection, when he closes the Dialog window, I need to retrieve the user's selected data from that Dialog window. How can I do that ?

Comment: Hack : During selection in the Dialog window, write values in hidden input tags in the parent window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you want to do is have the values saved when the dialog closes.  Let's say this is the page you are loading:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" /><br />
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" /><br />
<a href="#" id="dialog_submit_button">Click</a>
```

Then when you load the dialog, you should add this:

```
jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
    // all you other stuff
    close: function(){
        var in1 = $('#text1').val();
        var in2 = $('#text2').val();
        jQuery.dialog_info = {
            input1 : in1,
            input2 : in2
        }
    }
});
```

Now, those text values can be pulled anytime you need in the rest of the code with

```
var value1 = jQuery.dialog_info.input1;
var value2 = jQuery.dialog_info.input2;
```

Hope that helps