# JQuery UI before dialog opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, dwr

I have a very simple dialog box

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 300,
          width: 600,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
              }
        });
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

I am populating this dialog with a HTML table that has information passed into it from a Java method. I can get this working when the page is loaded but i want the information to load with the user opens the dialog box.

I have checked the API of jquery ui and the dialog has a beforeClose function but no beforeOpen function. What would be the best way of doing this? I have tried callbacks when the user opens the dialog box ( on the .show ) but i cannot get this working

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 300,
          width: 600,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
              }
        });
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).show(function(
            JavaClass.javaMethod();
          ));
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Try the open event: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Comment: this triggers it when the dialog is opened do, i need the Java call before the dialog is opened and i do not want the dialog to open until the Java call is finished

Comment: check if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837166/jquery-load-modal-dialog-contents-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       if (shouldOpenDialog()){ // Do what you must do here 
         $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                }
          });
         $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
       }
    });
 });
</script>
```

EDIT: Or, if your verification is asynchronous,

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#openDialog").on("click", function(){ 
       if (shouldOpenDialog(function() { // Do what you must do here 
         $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                }
          });
         $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
       });
    });
 });
</script>
```

having

```
function shouldOpenDialog(callback) {
   asyncCall(onComplete: function(o){
       if (o.ok) 
          callback();
   });
}
```