# How to POST form values to controller function(codeigniter) using jquery modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Actually i am trying to submit form and post values to controller function using jquery modal popup. 
But it's sending values in URL as parameters. i need to post values because values can be large that can be cause of "the requested url's length exceeds the capacity" error.
so, please help me how i can do it?

here is my js funciton.

```
function hierarchyManagementPrompt(){
 var width = 900;
 var height= 500;
 var resizablez=false;
 var address='top_menu/hierarchy_management_prompt/'; 

 var $form = $('#showBI'),
    $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),
    serializedData = $form.serialize();

           $.modal({
                    url: site_url+address,
                    data: serializedData,
                    title: 'Transfer Detail',
                    width:width,
                    resizable:resizablez,
                    height:height,
                    buttonsAlign : 'left',
                    buttons: {
                            '<img src="../resources/images/icons/fugue   /tick-circle.png">&nbsp;<span id="modelGoBtn">Back To Transfer</span>': function(win) {win.closeModal();}
                    }
                }); 
    warningMsg();}
```

Comment: Simple use jquery ajax and type post in your js

Comment: thanks for answer Harigovind R but i need to post this form using $.modal

Comment: @user3744619 if you are talking about Jquery UI Modals then yes You can add the Ajax  call for the modal function also

Comment: This might be some help for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837166/jquery-load-modal-dialog-contents-via-ajax

Comment: @vikram how i can add the ajax call for modal function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var form_data = {
         width : 900,
         height : 500,
         resizablez : false,
         address : 'top_menu/hierarchy_management_prompt/', 
         title: 'Transfer Detail',
         buttonsAlign : 'left',
};
```

ajax code change

```
$.modal({
     url: site_url+address,
     data: form_data,
     buttons: {
            '<img src="../resources/images/icons/fugue   /tick-circle.png">&nbsp;<span id="modelGoBtn">Back To Transfer</span>': function(win) {win.closeModal();}
                    }
                });
```

same as array argument passing etc.... to send data by ajax