# Coldfusion: Not getting data from a .cfm file

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I coded a popup in ColdFusion 11 and want to popup content from a .cfm file in my localhost.

[**TryCF.com Gist**](http://trycf.com/gist/34ac8475872928d6af73/acf11?theme=monokai)

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfwindow"> 

<cfform name="test"> 
    <cfinput type="button" name="x" value="S"  
        onClick="ColdFusion.Window.create('Window1', 'Member Listing -- Webpage Dialog','http://localhost/My_stuff/hello1.cfm',{x:100,y:100,height:300,width:300,modal:false,closable:true,draggable:true,resizable:true,center:true,initshow:true, 
minheight:200,minwidth:200 })"> 
</cfform>
```

But it doesn't show any content inside the popup when I run the code. I read about popup from the [ColdFusion.Window.create documenation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fbf.html).

Help me if I am missing something.

Comment: What happens if you call http://localhost/My_stuff/hello1.cfm in a browser?

Comment: Don't use `cfwindow`. All the ColdFusion UI components are outdated, severely limited and poorly implemented. Learn how to do this the right way with Bootstrap, jQuery, ExtJS, etc.

Comment: To answer your question, the example appears to be wrong.  Try changing the url to just `/My_stuff/hello1.cfm`. Having said that, agreed about ditching the CF ajax components. Using a newer, more robust library will save headaches in the long run.  Searching the archives will turn up plenty of examples, such as [jquery's dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837166/jquery-load-modal-dialog-contents-via-ajax#3837203), etcetera..

Comment: I know about Bootstrap, jQuery etc.. but i got a project related to ColdFusion...@Scott Stroz

Comment: @vipin. If nothing shows when you navigate a browser to hello1.cfm then your question isn't a problem with cfwindow. It's a problem with hello1.cfm. That's where you need to spend your time debugging. Why isn't hello1.cfm showing anything when you go to directly to that page in a browser. Maybe show us that cfm code and we can help.

Comment: Why was this down voted? The question is clear and the asker explains both the actual and expected results. Sadly the fault seems to lie in documentation (again). FWIW, if you read the example the "hello1.cfm" page is literally hard coded text *"... The hello1.cfm file can be as simple as the following line:"  `Hello from hello1.cfm`*. So the problem is NOT in hello1.cfm ;-)

Comment: @SamM, fixed my issue related to http://localhost/My_stuff/hello1.cfm. Now it showing me on localhost. Thanks

Comment: I think my localhost file is not getting to TryCF.com page. That's the problem. So i use <cfwindow> with a link to open popup and show content using <cfwindow>. I remove method (<cfform>) to get data content from localhost file.

Comment: @Leigh, the downvote is from me apparently. I must have accidentally clicked it. I'm trying to undo the down vote but SO says my down vote is locked until the question is edited.