# jquery modal window and opening a pdf file in new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I need to show listing of names of PDF files which are to be printed. I need to show this list in a JQuery Modal window. If anybody can please suggest as to how to redirect the view to a jquery modal window? I plan to use JQuery UI for the purpose.

My other requirement is to display the select PDF file in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a controller action that will return a partial view containing the list of PDF files. Then [configure jQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809035/ajax-jquery-ui-dialog-window-loaded-within-ajax-style-jquery-ui-tabs) to use AJAX in order to fetch this list from the server and show it in a `div`. Finally inside this list you could add `target="_blank"` to anchor elements pointing to the actual PDF file so that it is opened in a new window when the user clicks on this anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin for jquery . You pass it a web link and set it to iframe.

secondly, if you want to open up a pdf in a new window set the anchor link target="_blank" i.e. `<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_blank">title</a>`
hope that helps