# PHP url with parameter to open with JQUERY DIALOG?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I got a php code like below

```
print "<td width=61><a href='popupboxM.php?SId=$vv' onClick='openpopup(this.href);return false;'>".$row['Info']."</a></td>";
```

How can I open this in jquery ui dialog window ? currently I use javascript.

Plese help in for the same

Comment: i have been checking this in google for last two days and I messed up with codes, since I managed to download jquery ui and able to start a simple dialog popup but couldnt get a breakthrough in what I am looking !please give a hint/start ?

Comment: What's the url of the page you want to open in a popup?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery $.get() or $.post() to get the link and then insert it into a div, and then open that div as jquery ui dialog

Comment: I am new to jquery pls provide any links ?

Comment: see if these help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809035/ajax-jquery-ui-dialog-window-loaded-within-ajax-style-jquery-ui-tabs , http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: this is something close to what I am looking for [link](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/)