# Show page view as a jQuery-UI dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developoing a **Rails v2.3.2** app. A very basic Rails structure implemented as below:

I have a **controller**:

```
class SchoolController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def check_teachers
    @school = School.find params[:id]
    @teachers = @school.teachers
  end

end
```

my **route** definition in `route.rb`:

```
map.check_teachers, '/school/check_teachers/:id' :controller => :school, :action => :check_teachers
```

A **link** click will trigger the view:

```
link_to 'Check teachers', check_teachers_path(:id => @school.id)
```

**check_teachers**'s view `check_teachers.html.erb`:

```
<div>
Hello 
<%= render :partial => 'show_teachers'%>
</div>
```

I would like the **link click** to show the above view as a **jQuery-UI dialog** instead of a page view. How to achieve this??

**----Update-----**

Please check also my comment on @plaes 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the jQuery UI code to set up the dialog in `check_teachers.html.erb`:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});
</script>
<div id='dialog'>
Hello 
<%= render :partial => 'show_teachers'%>
</div>
```

Also, you need to include the required jQuery dependencies (jQuery and jQuery-UI). This is left as an exercise...

Comment: I forget to mention I have all the required js libraries set up. So, that is not in consideration in my case. I actually tried your way before I post, since I have the route.rb configuration, the link click will always render an new empty page then the popup dialog is on top of the empty page, but I want it to show on the previous original page.

Comment: OK, then you need to load your dialog with the AJAX request.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809035/ajax-jquery-ui-dialog-window-loaded-within-ajax-style-jquery-ui-tabs

Answer (score 1):

By default, it renders an html page.
Just before closing the controller add this code

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

Rename your view to check_teachers.js.erb
Inside this file, include your necessary jquery.