# jQuery Modal Dialog

Tags: php, html

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've been working on, and I've managed to put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testdialog.php) jQuery Modal Dialog box and it works fine.

What I'm now trying to do is to link [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/test.php) page to the dialog box via a button click, to be specific the 'Upload Image(s)' button.

On the button click, the dialog box correctly appears on screen, but rather than it hovering over the main page which it's called from, it appears on a seperate web browser page.

I've been working on this for days now and I just can't seem to get around the problem. I don't think the problem is with the dialog box code, but most likely in how I call the opening of it. i.e. having two submit buttons on the main form, means that I have called the page as shown below 
because I wasn't sure how to deal with both of the 'submit' buttons for this particular scenario.

```
<form name="savemyfindstolocation" id="savemyfindstolocation" method="post" action="testdialog.php">
```

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going absolutely wrong mate. You have created a form with the action as **testdialog.php** which is the dialog form, if I'm not wrong.
You've given the button **Upload Image** as `type="submit"`, which would SUBMIT the form ofcourse, as it is doing now.
To open a dialog, you will require to use either an input button with **`type="button"`** or a link/anchor with an `onClick` event.
Can you please tell where is your dialog located and how are you working with the dialog?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. You're absolutely right in that the 'testdialog.php' is my dialog box. My dialog box is located on my server as a separate file, and it's use is basically to allow the user to upload images, and that functionality works fine. I hope I've given you all you need. Kind regards

Comment: Cool. so now how you gotta work is, just keep the inner information (like to show the upload image form, the after-processing error/success form/message things) in the testdialog.php page. On the Upload Image button/link, call the dialog box with the testdialog.php as url parameter. If there is no URL parameter, get data from testdialog.php using ajax and show it in the dialog box. Hope you got it.

Comment: Hi, forgive me for being really dumb. I understand that I need to basically leave the testdialog.php page alone, but I'm relatively new to this, so could you perhaps elborate on the URL parameter option. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: With this, I hope you know how to use AJAX.
Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809035/ajax-jquery-ui-dialog-window-loaded-within-ajax-style-jquery-ui-tabs