# How to get a div to pop over limits of an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, dynamics-crm-2016

I have used Spectrum color picker in a CRM form as a web resource, which I think is effectively an IFRAME and I would like the contents of the IFRAME (a div) to pop over its limits, over on the parent document. I don't want the IFRAME itself to acommodate the size of the div that's expanding because that'll make the form ugly.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color Picker</title>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery.1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../Spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Spectrum/spectrum.css" />
        <script>
            $(document)
            .ready(function () {
                $("#full").spectrum({
                    color: "#ECC",
                    showInput: true,
                    className: "full-spectrum",
                    showInitial: true,
                    showPalette: false,
                    showSelectionPalette: false,
                    maxSelectionSize: 10,
                    preferredFormat: "hex",
                    localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
                    move: function (color) {

                    },
                    show: function () {

                    },
                    beforeShow: function () {

                    },
                    hide: function () {

                    },
                    change: function() {

                    }
                });


            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' id="full" style="position:absolute;"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought of playing with `z-index` but that seems to be working only for images.

Here's what this produces in the form:

[image]

I would like the div that the blue arrow is pointing at, to pop over the field below.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible.

This is a dup of these answers (and probably many others):

[Extend div outside bounds of iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081821/extend-div-outside-bounds-of-iframe)

[Overflow content outside of HTML Frame Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479930/overflow-content-outside-of-html-frame-element)